# Python/Selenium output nested list from scraping a web page to create a table on Google Sheets

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, google-sheets, nested-lists

I need to create a nested list of text which I am extracting through Python/Selenium to write onto a Google Sheet. The data comes from the following html page example:

```
<tr class="dayHeader">
 <td colspan="7" style="padding:10px 0;"><hr>
  <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;Tuesday - 02 February 2021</h5>
 </td></tr>

<tr class="header">
 <td class="col0">Time</td>
 <td class="col1">Name</td>
 <td class="col4">Duration</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>
  <span class="col0Item">06:00<span>
 </td>
 <td>
  <span class="col1Item"></span>
 </td>
 <td>
  <span class="col4Item"></span>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Globally, it looks like so ("dayHeader" as the main header for each different table):

> dayHeader

| col0 | col1 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| col0Item | col1Item | col4Item |
| col0Item | col1Item | col4Item |
| col0Item | col1Item | col4Item |

There are up to 15 (but this value can vary) "dayHeader" tables on a page, which are parent to rows col0Item, col1Item, etc.

What I want to do is to output scraped data into a nested list, as follows:

```
variable1 = "Page1_string"

nested_list1 = [
[dayHeader,col0Item,col1Item,variable1,col4Item],
[dayHeader,col0Item,col1Item,variable1,col4Item],
[dayHeader,col0Item,col1Item,variable1,col4Item]
]

nested_list2 = [
[dayHeader,col0Item,col1Item,variable1,col4Item],
[dayHeader,col0Item,col1Item,variable1,col4Item],
[dayHeader,col0Item,col1Item,variable1,col4Item]
]
```

"variable1" is a fixed variable per page.

"dayHeader" text changes every new table (so, up to 15 per page).

"col*Item" text changes every new row.

Currently, I am only able to output in the following manner...

```
col0_select = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='col0Item']")
col0_list_output = [element.text for element in col0_select]

print(col0_list_output) = [col0Item,col0Item,col0Item,col0Item]
```

It isn't the preferred method because it takes apart data from rows into columns, which means that something will go wrong if for whatever reason col0_list_output and col1_list_output etc don't have the same length.

How can I output nested_list1, nested_list2, etc, as explained above? Perhaps, the best would be to iterate through classes and append list when class = dayHeader or col0Item or col1Item or col4Item (if statements). But not sure how to do this.

Additionally, say a certain cell is empty, how can I translate it into an empty string?

Comment: I think what I'd need to do is that when I hit the first dayHeader, everything else (col*Item) until the next dayHeader is part of the same list. Then I can replicate the same method for each row of the table.